# How do I dynamically add Source to existing Graph?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

What can be alternative to dynamically changing running graph ? Here is my situation. I have graph that ingests articles into DB. Articles come from 3 plugins in different format. Thus I have several flows

```
val converterFlow1: Flow[ImpArticle, Article, NotUsed]
val converterFlow2: Flow[NewsArticle, Article, NotUsed]
val sinkDB: Sink[Article, Future[Done]]

// These are being created every time I poll plugins    
val sourceContentProvider : Source[ImpArticle, NotUsed]
val sourceNews : Source[NewsArticle, NotUsed]
val sourceCit : Source[Article, NotUsed]

val merged = Source.combine(
    sourceContentProvider.via(converterFlow1),
    sourceNews.via(converterFlow2),
    sourceCit)(Merge(_))

val res = merged
  .buffer(10, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
  .toMat(sinkDB)(Keep.both)
  .run()
```

Problem is that I get data from content provider once per 24 hrs, from news once per 2 hrs and last source may come at any time because it's coming from humans.

I realize that graphs are immutable but how I can periodically attach new instances of `Source` to my graph so that I have single point of throttling of the process of ingesting ?

UPDATE: You can say my data is stream of `Source`-s, three sources in my case. But I cannot change that because I get instances of `Source` from external classes (so called plugins). These plugins work independently from my ingestion class. I can't combine them into one gigantic class to have single `Source`.

Comment: It's not exactly clear why do you need to attach new sources. You said that you have data from the content provider, from news and something entered manually; therefore, you have three sources, no more, no less. So your code looks fine to me.

Comment: I periodically get new instances of `Source` class at arbitrary time that need to be ingested. Thus I want to avoid situation when I'm ingesting 10K articles from content provider and in the middle of it I get `Source` from news with 2K items. I'd like them to be ingested simultaneously and respect my single throttling rule.

Comment: I would suggest to model your data stream not as a sequence of `Source`s but rather as a single `Source` which yields all the data sequentially. Then the `Merge` combinator should be enough. I'm not really sure how your design would avoid the situation you've described, BTW.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Not sure I understand. I updated the question.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev There may be other ways to make this code work, but I am very interested in the question presented because it has many other applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, in general the correct way would be to join a stream of sources into a single source, i.e. go from `Source[Source[T, _], Whatever]` to `Source[T, Whatever]`. This can be done with [`flatMapConcat`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.7/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Source@flatMapConcat[T,M](f:Out=%3Eakka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SourceShape[T],M]):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]) or with [`flatMapMerge`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.7/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Source@flatMapMerge[T,M](breadth:Int,f:Out=%3Eakka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SourceShape[T],M]):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]). Therefore, if you can get a `Source[Source[Article, NotUsed], NotUsed]`, you can use one of `flatMap*` variants and obtain a final `Source[Article, NotUsed]`. Do it for each of your sources (no pun intended), and then your original approach should work.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented code based up on answer given by Vladimir Matveev and want to share it with others since it looks like common use-case to me.

I knew about `Source.queue` which Viktor Klang mentioned but I wasn't aware of  `flatMapConcat`. It's pure awesomeness.

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("root")
implicit val executor = system.dispatcher
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

case class ImpArticle(text: String)
case class NewsArticle(text: String)
case class Article(text: String)

val converterFlow1: Flow[ImpArticle, Article, NotUsed] = Flow[ImpArticle].map(a => Article("a:" + a.text))
val converterFlow2: Flow[NewsArticle, Article, NotUsed] = Flow[NewsArticle].map(a => Article("a:" + a.text))
val sinkDB: Sink[Article, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach { a =>
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  println(a)
}

// These are being created every time I poll plugins
val sourceContentProvider: Source[ImpArticle, NotUsed] = Source(List(ImpArticle("cp1"), ImpArticle("cp2")))
val sourceNews: Source[NewsArticle, NotUsed] = Source(List(NewsArticle("news1"), NewsArticle("news2")))
val sourceCit: Source[Article, NotUsed] = Source(List(Article("a1"), Article("a2")))

val (queue, completionFut) = Source
  .queue[Source[Article, NotUsed]](10, backpressure)
  .flatMapConcat(identity)
  .buffer(2, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
  .toMat(sinkDB)(Keep.both)
  .run()

queue.offer(sourceContentProvider.via(converterFlow1))
queue.offer(sourceNews.via(converterFlow2))
queue.offer(sourceCit)
queue.complete()

completionFut.onComplete {
  case Success(res) =>
    println(res)
    system.terminate()
  case Failure(ex) =>
    ex.printStackTrace()
    system.terminate()
}

Await.result(system.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)
```

I'd still check success of `Future` returned by `queue.offer` but in my case these calls will be pretty infrequent.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot model it as a `Source[Source[_,_],_]` then I'd consider using a `Source.queue[Source[T,_]](queueSize, overflowStrategy)`: [here](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.7/index.html#akka.stream.javadsl.Source$@queue[T](bufferSize:Int,overflowStrategy:akka.stream.OverflowStrategy):akka.stream.javadsl.Source[T,akka.stream.javadsl.SourceQueueWithComplete[T]])

What you'll have to be careful about though is what happens if submission fails.