# How would you detect that substream was processed when using flatMapConcat?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

It's development of following question that I asked recently:
[How do I dynamically add Source to existing Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944150/how-do-i-dynamically-add-source-to-existing-graph)

Assume you have source queue of elements `Source[T, NotUsed]`. You put substream via `.offer()` call. How would you detect that substream was fully processed when using `flatMapConcat` ?

I tried putting `Promise[T]` at the end of substream but there is no guaranty that elements that precede it wouldn't be processed slower. Here is code that demonstrates the issue

```
trait PipeElement
case class Link(url: String) extends PipeElement
case class Ids(ids: List[Int]) extends PipeElement
case class Title(text: String) extends PipeElement
case class Completion(p: Promise[Unit]) extends PipeElement

val (queue, completionFut) = Source
  .queue[Source[PipeElement, NotUsed]](10, backpressure)
  .flatMapConcat(identity)
  .buffer(2, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
  .mapAsync(4) {
    case Link(url) => Future{
      Thread.sleep(500)
      Some("url: " + url)
    }
    case Ids(ids) => Future{
      Some("ids: " + ids)
    }
    case Title(title) => Future{
      Some("title: " + title)
    }
    case Completion(p) =>
      p.success(Unit)
      Future.successful(Some("Promise delivered"))
  }
  .toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.both)
  .run()

val promise = Promise[Unit]()
val lst = List(Link("Link"), Ids(List(1,2,3)), Title("title"), Completion(promise))
queue.offer(Source(lst))
queue.offer(Source(List(Link("Link2"), Link("Link3"))))
queue.complete()

promise.future.onComplete {
  case Success(res) =>
    println("promise: " + res)
    // system.terminate()
  case Failure(ex) =>
    ex.printStackTrace()
    system.terminate()
}

completionFut.onComplete {
  case Success(res) =>
    println("Stream is finished: " + res)
    system.terminate()
  case Failure(ex) =>
    ex.printStackTrace()
    system.terminate()
}

Await.result(system.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)
```

Output is

```
promise: ()
Some(url: Link)
Some(ids: List(1, 2, 3))
Some(title: title)
Some(Promise delivered)
Some(url: Link2)
Some(url: Link3)
Stream is finished: Done
```

I can fix this by returning `Either[Promise[Unit], String]` from `mapAsync` and later filtering/collecting over elements like this

```
.collect {
  case Left(p) if {
    p.success(Unit)
    false
  } => ???
  case Right(v) => v
}
```

It works but looks too hacky to me :)

Ideas?

Comment: Near the end of this blog post it talks about message acknowledgement: http://eng.localytics.com/akka-streams-akka-without-the-actors/

Comment: Are you referring to `onComplete` ? I can do that only on outer `Source`.

Comment: Have you considered using a counter? You could zip the source in question with some kind of marker (and probably the elements in the other sources with a different marker to end up with the same type), and count the elements having the desired marker in the resulting stream.